# Median values with aggregate very different from with boxplot in ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, aggregate, boxplot

I have a dataframe `df` like so:

```
    subj lang  mod    L_prnt    cohort
1   a1   eng   prnt   0.498529  EL1
2   a1   eng   spch   0.151919  EL1
3   a1   heb   prnt   0.428959  EL1
4   a1   heb   spch  -0.098831  EL1
5   b1   eng   prnt   0.318330  HL1
6   b1   eng   spch   0.212678  HL1
.
.
.
400 b54  heb   spch   0.356721  HL1
```

All variables except `L_prnt` are factors.

I want to draw a `geom_boxplot`, which gives me the values separated by `lang`, `cohort` faceted by `mod`. The following code gives me an output that looks good:

```
ggplot(df) +
   geom_boxplot(aes(x=lang, y=df[,L_prnt], colour = cohort)) +
   facet_grid(. ~mod)
```

With my full dataframe (with a couple of unimportant theme changes), this is the output:
[image]

But if I look at the median values of each of these, using the `aggregate` function like so:

```
aggregate(L_prnt ~ cohort + lang + mod, data=df, FUN = median)
```

Then I get the following output:

```
     cohort lang  mod   L_prnt
1    EL1    eng   prnt  0.3344170 
2    HL1    eng   prnt  0.4340280
3    EL1    heb   prnt  0.1632390
4    HL1    heb   prnt  0.4673595
5    EL1    eng   spch  0.0747170
6    HL1    eng   spch  0.0782405
7    EL1    heb   spch  0.0764705 
8    HL1    heb   spch  0.0776450
```

These are obviously very different from the median values that I see in the boxplot. The boxplot shows me that the `heb` values are lower across the board, while the median values show me that the `spch` values are lower across the board.

What am I getting wrong?

Comment: How many observations do you have per unique lang-cohort-mod combination? It says so in the documentation for geom_boxplot says: " ... differs slightly from the method used by the boxplot function, and may be apparent with small samples "

Comment: indeed Median is a percentile (50th) and they are many ways to calculate them. See option `type` in the fonction `quantile`. With this fonction you might be able to retrieve exactly the value shows in the boxplot choosing the right type

Comment: The N is not bad (although not huge), 46 for all values of EL1 and 54 for HL1.
But this doesn't seem to be an issue of slight differences - the values are completely off, and more importantly the *relative* values are completely and utterly different.

Comment: Can you add your data (with `dput`) so that we can confirm this occurrence? I've tried playing around with a couple builtin data sets, but none of them show this difference. (If you use a subset of the data, please ensure that this still happens.)

Comment: I've tried with random data `(L_prnt =runif(400,-0.5,1.5))`, and I see no difference also. The only problem I see in you code is: `y=df[,L_prnt]` in the `aes`, it should be `y=L_prnt`. If you still have the problem, use dput() to share with us

Comment: I confirm after using `df$L_prnt` in the `aes` that it does change the result (Since now the column is not anymore associate to the other factor), change `y=df[,L_prnt]` to `y=L_prnt`.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to have been the problem! I am not quite sure *why* it is a problem however...

Comment: One more related question - the reason I had `y=df[,"L_prnt"]` in the first place, is that I want this to loop over a number of different strings, producing a separate plot for each one, so originally it was `y=df[,i]`, with `i` as a variable name. However, if I try and do this with `y=i`, then it doesn't work, I get a plot with single bars at 0. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: You probably need `aes_string`. In your question, you did not have quotes around `L_print` within `aes`. Is it possible that `L_print` was a variable (in addition to being a column) that stored either a character or an integer that indexed to a different column?

Comment: Yes, `L_prnt` was actually a vector, so it was doing the completely wrong thing. Using `aes_string` seems to have solved it, the median lines on the plot match up properly to the `aggregate` values now!

Comment: I'm not sure of the etiquette here (I'm a pretty new user...). Should I write an answer in order to show that this is solved, or will one of you?